# Prove $A-A'$ has a discrete subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

I am asked to prove this: Let $A$ be a subset of the topological space $X$ and $A'$ be its set of limit points. Then $A-A'$ has a discrete subspace topology.

I think the key to prove this is to show every single-point subset of $A-A'$ is open and thus any subset of $A-A'$ is open, right?

Answer (score 1):

> I think the key to prove this is to show every single-point subset of A−A′ is open and thus any subset of A−A′ is open, right?

Yes. Let's write $B=A\setminus A'$.

Consider $a$ in $B$. Then $a$ is in $A$ but is not a limit point of $A$. This means that there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $a$ (for the topology $\cal T$ of $X$) such that $V\cap A=\{a\}$.

Since $V$ is a neighborhood of $a$, there exists an open set $O$ in $\cal T$ such that $a\in O\subset V$. Clearly $O\cap A=\{a\}$.

But since $a\notin A'$, we have $O\cap B=O\cap(A\setminus A')=\{a\}$. By definition of the subspace topology, this means that $\{a\}$ is open in the subspace topology of $B$ induced by $\cal T$. This implies that every subset of $B$ is open (arbitrary unions of open sets are open), so the subspace topology of $B$ is discrete.